# Показ старых и новых данных и вектора

Tags: c++, qt

Пытаюсь сделать следующию логику.
1. Сначала на карту распологается начальная точка. 
2. После того как точка существует, ее можно передвигать.
3. При передвижении, должные указываться старые и новые координаты точки.

Как нарисовать точку, получить координаты в вектор и тд все уже работает.
Так же я могу ее передвигать, то есть, при первом нажатии, точка получает статус и каждое следующие нажатие на карту, это перемещение.

Обновление выводимых данных, проиходит в QTimer каждую секунду, после того как мы выбрали точку.

Объясните пожалуйста, как организовать вывод старых и новых данные. То есть, при втором передвижении, координаты которые были до этого сохраняются в другие переменные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стэк координат подойдёт (`QStack<QPoint>`)?

Каждое перемещение - добавляете новую точку с координатами. 
У вас так даже получится поддерживать отмену перемещений.

По таймеру просто обходите стэк ( QStack наследуется от QVector, его можно обойти используя итераторы, к примеру) и рисуете координаты.

Ну и считаете что актуальные координаты всегда на вершине стэка.

Про вектора только не понял.

Comment: а зачем QPoint? Просто я использую struct как вектор.

Comment: struct как вектор ? В смысле ? У Вас самописная структура - контейнер для чего-либо ? Или struct  как Vector2D (на плоскости) ?  В любом случае, QStack позволяет хранить любые классы, главное чтобы у них были конструкторы копирования + дефолтный (пустой), и оператор присваивания.
А QPoint - потому-что `A QPoint object can also be used as a vector`  - [QPoint](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qpoint.html)